# How can I force WordPress to redirect to canonical permalinks?

Tags: permalinks, redirect, slug

In WordPress 3.1 a post can be reached a number of ways, for example each one of these takes you to the same post (where /id is the base)

```
http://myblog.com/id/1008
http://myblog.com/id/1008/my-slug
http://myblog.com/my-slug
```

How can I tell WordPress to redirect all of these variations to

```
http://myblog.com/id/1008/my-slug
```

?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Check whether the posts not being redirected actually have the correct permalink stored in the DB. There's a bug in which canonicals can't be properly guessed because the permalink structure was CHANGED after the post was created.

Try either creating a new post with your current permalink structure, or editing the post_name DB field for them. (There's a plugin for updating the permalinks in DB)

The question remains. 
ASSUMING it is still happening:

How do we FORCE wordpress to REDIRECT to the canonical url?
No just adding a link to it, but REDIRECTING to that page.

I changed the permalinks structure of the site, and added a add_rewrite_rule in functions.php, so now the old `/02/20/2008/postname` addresses are accepted and canonicalized as `/blob/postname` correctly… and the page is found successfully.

But no matter what I do, the canonical just stays as a link in the old URL'd page, still showing the wrong url in the adress bar.

NO REDIRECT is performed.

Ive worked with another website before, and I ended up (after days of trying tens of different pieces of code) using .htaccess redirects.

I know .htaccess redirects will work, but now that I read everywhere that "It should" be doing it… I'm wondering: Should it? and more exactly "how do I FORCE it?

Answer (score 3):

WordPress should do this automatically. Whatever permalink format you have set in Settings > Permalinks should be the URL visitors end up at when they come to a different URL that indicates the same content.

Answer (score 1):

I use a plugin called Redirection (http://urbangiraffe.com/plugins/redirection/) that allows me to set up rules for url redirection. This might suit your needs if you can't get WordPress to do what you want.

James :-)

Answer (score 1):

wordpress does it automatically there is no need to do any thing if you have a custom structure defined in the settings->permalinks it will automatically redirect all the incoming structures to your custom structure or the one you have chosen in the settings in wp back end

Answer (score 0):

```
/**
 * Creates 301 redirects canonical
 */

function bm_redirect_can() {
 
   // Is single Post
   if ( is_single() ) {
        global $wp;
        $wp->parse_request();
         $current_url = trim(home_url($wp->request), "/");
         $redirect = get_permalink();
         $surl = trim($redirect, "/");      
        if($current_url != $surl){
            wp_redirect( $redirect, 301 );
            exit;
        }
   }
    
}
add_action( 'template_redirect', 'bm_redirect_can' );
```

I got multiple emails about canonical issue. If I have 2 categories both category URL was indexed with proper one canonical tag and both pages able to access.

Example:
https://www.blandmagazine.com/lifestyle/trendiest-messy-hair-buns/
https://www.blandmagazine.com/fashion/trendiest-messy-hair-buns/

This has not been automatically done by WP. Many paid plugins are available but programatically I have done above code and working.